# How to see if a list is within another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am making a simple program to return True/False if the login details supplied by the user match the details in a list.

```
...
details = [['Charlie', 'Password'],
           ['Turnbull', 'Password']]

def authenticate():
    login_details = get_entry_values()  # list of user input [username, password]
    for username, password in details:
        if login_details[0] == username and login_details[1] == password:
            print("Authenticated")
            return True
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            return False
```

However when I enter the first login details ('Charlie' followed by 'Password') it returns True but when I enter the second it returns False

Comment: Don't use a list but rather a dictionary: `{'Charlie': 'password', 'Turnbull': 'password'}`, then `if details.get(login_details[0], None) == login_details[1]` (make sure `get_entry_values` only returns strings)

Comment: You are returning result for whatever first item in `details` is. You will never reach any further to check against following values.

Comment: Please show the code for *get_entry_values()*

Comment: Using a debugger would have demonstrated the problem *very* quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a list of lists, and you want to see whether a given list is in the list of lists, you don't need to loop over the list.  You can just do:

```
def authenticate():
    login_details = get_entry_values()
    if login_details in details:
        print("Authenticated")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        return False
```

If you don't want to print anything (which you probably shouldn't, as this makes code reuse harder) then the function can be reduced to:

```
    def authenticate():
        return get_entry_values() in details
```

However, let's go back to your original code and see what the problem is with it.  It's simple: you only ever check the first password in the list. Your `if` statement always returns, whether there was a match or not, and so the code never considers the second or subsequent items in `details`.  What you need to do is *keep checking* if you don't get a match.  In other words, the password cannot be declared incorrect until you have finished the loop. So:

```
def authenticate():
    login_details = get_entry_values()  # list of user input [username, password]
    for username, password in details:
        if login_details[0] == username and login_details[1] == password:
            print("Authenticated")
            return True
    print("Incorrect")
    return False
```

As others have noted in comments, a dictionary is a better data structure for storing user names and passwords. If you used a dictionary, you wouldn't need a loop at all:

```
details = {'Charlie': 'Password',
           'Turnbull': 'Password'}

def authenticate():
    username, password = get_entry_values()
    authenticated = details.get(username) == password
    print("Authenticated" if authenticated else "Incorrect")
    return authenticated
```

The use of `dict.get()` here returns `None` if the username isn't in the dictionary, and `None` is never equal to any string, so this is effectively checking both that the username exists and that the password is correct at the same time.